# Conflict in version dependency in Android Gradle

Tags: java, android, http, gradle, kotlin

I need to add dependency RESTMock, but I get this error in Gradle.

```
 project :app > com.github.andrzejchm.RESTMock:android:0.3.3 > com.github.andrzejchm.RESTMock:core:0.3.3 > com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-tls:3.13.1
```

but I use com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-tls:3.12.1 in project.

I need version 3.12.1 and RESTMock together, anyway can I have together?

Answer (score 2):

try update

```
com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-tls:3.12.1
```

to

```
com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-tls:3.13.1
```

Maybe **com.github.andrzejchm.RESTMock:core:0.3.3** needs a newer version of okhttp

Comment: I need to com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-tls:3.12.1, can i dont change?

Comment: So try downgrade RESTMock, look this https://github.com/andrzejchm/RESTMock/blob/master/README.md, here it says that this lib works with the top versions of okhttp

Comment: I need together

Comment: I know work this solution but I need to keep 2 version